# How to ask Mathematica to convert ArcCosh to ArcCos

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In the situlation like

```
I ArcCosh[x]
```

which is either

`ArcCos[x]` or `-ArcCos[x]`.

How to force Mma to do this?

Comment: @Jim: Cos[ix]=Cosh[x], then ...

Comment: Best way to learn something new on the internet:  post something wrong, then sit back and let the corrections roll in.  Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica wont do this because it is not correct in general: It is easy to find (complex) numbers for which this 'identity' does not hold:

```
In[1]:=Table[{I ArcCos[y],ArcCosh[y]}//Chop,{y,{0.5,-0.5-0.5I}}]
Out[1]={{1.0472 I,1.0472 I},{-0.530638+2.02307 I,0.530638-2.02307 I}}
```

If you want to force Mathematica you can either convince yourself that the identity holds in the cases you are interested in and then input it by hand, or you can tell Mathematica about your assumptions:

```
In[2]:= Assuming[{-1<y<1}, FullSimplify[I ArcCos[y]]]
Out[2]= ArcCosh[y]
```

HTH

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you are saying not always I ArcCosh[x]=ArcCos[x] or I ArcCosh[x]=-ArcCos[x], correct? The two examples you gave, one is true but not the other.

Comment: @Qiang Li: Aah, now I understand your question: So you are saying that I ArcCosh[x] is always one of +/- ArcCos[x], but the sign depends on x. This is probably true, and I so you should be able to get the sign by throwing in enough assumptions to uniquely define it.